# Find like Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo una query en Mongoose como esta:

`Categoria.find(query, "_id nombre")`

Esa variable `query` es de la busqueda que voy a hacer, y quiero que tenga un LIKE (como el de la sentencia SQL, pero por el comentario de Mauricio Contreras es ineficiente, entonces si hay una manera mejor buenisimo) en la propiedad `nombre`.

Estoy completandola así:

```
let query = { estado: true };
if (req.query.nombre) {
    query.nombre = req.query.nombre;
}
```

Como podría hacer que `query.nombre` lo busque como si fuese un LIKE en Mongoose? Porque se como hacerlo directamente en el `find`.

`Categoria.find({ nombre: /query.nombre/ }, "_id nombre")`

Pero necesito primero chequear que nombre sea distinto de undefined por eso armo la query antes. Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias!

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que tenga un LIKE? ¿Tal vez te refieres a la búsqueda nada eficiente de SQL que usa la  sentencia LIKE? Porque de resto no comprendo lo que deseas lograr. Si pudieras aclarar un poco más esto, te podría ayudar. Saludos

Comment: Ahi edite, si me refería al LIKE de la sentencia SQL. Aunque si es ineficiente no se que seria mejor, eso lo había leído en la docu de Mongoose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes apoyarte haciendo uso de una [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```
let query = { estado: true };
if (req.query.nombre) {
  var regex = new RegExp(req.query.nombre, "i")
  query.nombre = regex;
}
```

Y en caso de que no funcione podrías intentar con `new RegExp('^' + req.query.nombre + '$', "i")`;

Comment: Muchas gracias @ricardo-dlc. Tu respuesta me sirvió perfectamente! Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes meter una expresión regular con el operador [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

```
const nombre = req.query.nombre;
Categoria.find( { nombre: { $regex: `.*${ nombre }.*` } } );
```

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, si bien serviría, me quedo con la que me dio @ricardo-dlc ya que me permite realizar mas filtros!